# DATETIME de MySQL me carga el dato 0000-00-00

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

Quiero hacer un INSERT, con datos tomados de SQL server, donde verifique que el dato que contiene la fila con fecha y hora es DATETIME, entonces en mi MySQL lo puse como tal, el tema es que al hacer el INSERT me lo carga con `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Con PHP le pongo a la variable de fecha asi :

```
<td><?=$row1[7]->format('d-m-Y:H:i:s')?></td>
```

Lo puse en una variable para hacer luego el INSERT en MySQL:

```
$fecha1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row1[7]->format('d-m-Y:H:i:s'));
```

Pero no sé si es correcto esto así, si pudiera pedir una ayuda os agradeceré!

Comment: Bueno y el problema cuál sería?... Probaste el código y te salió algún error?...

Comment: El error, es que me figure ``0000-00-00`` ya que al hacer el INSERT tiene una fecha y hora traída de SQL server con demás datos.

Comment: Prueba colocando una fecha con este formato 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z ajústale las horas y pruebas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te carga con `0000-00-00 00:00:00` porque hay un error en el formato de tu fecha.

El formato debería de ser algo como esto: `format('Y-m-d H:i:s')`